# Reverse engineering of Process manager apk

Tags: android, malware, apk

Is there someone helps me to understand how to build the server of this apk https://lab52.io/blog/complete-dissection-of-an-apk-with-a-suspicious-c2-server/ ? I tried to disassemble the apk but it is obfuscated and I don’t know how can proceed